# replace_tag() receiving NULL for field data

Tags: fieldtype

I am creating my own custom field type, and my replace_tag function is as follows:

```
function replace_tag($data, $params = array(), $tagdata = FALSE) {

    return $data; // NULL

}
```

The problem, as noted in the code, is that `$data` has no value. I have verified that the channel entry i'm display is correct, that field's data is properly stored in the database, and that if I manually set a value for `$data` inside the `replace_tag()` function, it prints to the template just fine.

Any suggestions as to what could be going wrong?

Thanks!

P.S. [I started a thread here](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/237035/) but never got responses. Trying this instead.

Comment: Are you using a pre_process function in your fieldtype? If so, you might check to ensure that it's not returning null.

Comment: That ended up being the cause of the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Rob Sanchez, my pre_process function wasn't returning field data.

If you have the pre_process function in your fieldtype class file but it doesn't return the $data parameter that it accepts, nothing will get passed to the replace_tag() function.

(**Edit**: clarity)

Comment: Please consider adding more information to your answer to help future users if they come across the same problem.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip. Just added more to this post.

Comment: Also, you can select your answer as "correct" by clicking on the checkmark http://screencast.com/t/6Mus8tHrTRN